# how to change index of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to change the index of an array after doing some operations
My actual output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
        )
    [5] => Array
       (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
        )

)
```

I want to be something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
        )
    [2] => Array
       (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 7
        )

)
```

How to achieve this in php???? Thanks in advance

Comment: `array_values()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract only the values to a new array and the keys will be indexed from `0`:

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: I've been searching this for days. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 2):

The `array_values()` function returns only values from array.

Thus, resetting all the array keys to numeric starting from `0, 1, 2, ...`

You can do it using

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "array_values" Function for that.
Please refer this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php